# Searching for usable implementation of CSP on top of pkcs 11

Tags: pkcs#11

I found a few dead projects on this title.

Some referenced [here](https://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/WindowsCSP#CSP11).

I need one. But why are they all dead?
Is it bad idea to use such design? do you know of any good implementation which does this?

Comment: Probably there's no demand for such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Some Smart Card [vendors](http://www.gemalto.com) were providing CSP over PKCS#11 (not open source). In my opitnion, htis is not the best way of developping a CSP. These 2 standards are very different, and even more different since the venue of CNG and Credential Providers under 'recent' Windows OS.